# Is a non-Jew reliable for Sha'atnez?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, inspection, shaatnez, trust-neemanut

Suppose someone is fabulously wealthy, and they have their own personal tailor who is not Jewish. May this tailor be relied upon not to make anything which contains Sha'atnez? May this tailor be relied upon to check for Sha'atnez in his materials or in whole garments purchased elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Per Yalkut Yosef when you purchase clothing from a non Jew you have to inspect them for Shaatnez even if the non Jew insists there is no linen threads. However if linen threads are significantly more expensive then one may rely on that fact. If one supplied the material to a non Jew we are not afraid that he will switch the goods, since it can be checked.

http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_60.html#HtmpReportNum0004_L2

> סימן שב - נאמנות גוי בשעטנז א הקונה בגדי צמר מנכרי צריך לבדקם, שמא הם
>   תפורים בחוט פשתן. [כשיש שם מיעוט המצוי של תערובת צמר ופשתים]. ואפילו
>   אם הנכרי מסיח לפי תומו שתפרו בחוט שאינו פשתן, אינו נאמן, אך במקום
>   שהפשתן ביוקר יש לסמוך להתיר. [ומה שכתבו הפוסקים להתיר רק בדיעבד, היינו
>   כשחוט הקנבוס קשה לתפירה, אבל היום שכל החוטים שוין לתפירה שרי לכתחלה
>   כאשר הפשתן יקר יותר]. ואם נתן לנכרי חוטים שאינם פשתן שיתפור בהם עבורו
>   בגד מותר, ואין חוששין שמא יחליפם, מאחר שאפשר לבדקם, וכן המנהג. [שם
>   סימן שב ס''א]

Comment: What if you instruct the tailor not to use shatnez, but he goes out and purchases the material?

Comment: Right, @Daniel has captured the essence of my question. I don't think this answers that.

Comment: The text here discusses purchasing from a non-Jew, not a non-Jew who is employed by or contracted to a Jew.

Comment: @SethJ Perhaps you can elaborate why you think there would be a difference (eg. the non-Jew has more to lose by lying).

Comment: @GershonGold, you could improve this answer by [edit]ing in additional information about how parts of the quoted source apply to the question at hand.

Comment: You added the word "significantly" in your summary.

Comment: @doubleAA: B'Yoker to my understanding means "significantly" more. That is why the original is there for the reader to translate on their own.

Comment: @GershonGold If so, then how would you say "more expensive" without "significantly" in Hebrew?

Comment: @DoubleAA: יקר יותר